# How to retrieve desktop wallpapers on a multi-monitor display

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors

I found a way to get a wallpaper path from the primary screen, but If I have 2 or more displays, how would i go about getting the wallpaper image/setting the wallpaper image of each of these monitors?
I have an array of Screens, but that only gives me dimensions and some other properties, How can I create an array of images in which each index contains the wallpaper of that wallpaper.

For example:

```
Wallpaperarray[0] = //Monitor 1 wallpaper
Wallpaperarray[1] = //Monitor 2 wallpaper
```

*There isn't necessarily 2 monitors, there might be 3 or more.

Comment: Use the [IDesktopWallpaper::GetWallpaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706957(v=vs.85).aspx) method.